# How to replace {\'{\i} by {\'i} with sed

Tags: sed, special-characters, bibtex

I'm using Papers3 to export a Bibtex library, but there are errors with some of the accents. Many come out missing a curly brace, and therefore give a compilation error when I run bibtex. Here is an example of an error in the bib file:

```
author = {Combi, J A and Rib{\'o}, M and Mart{\'{\i}, J and Chaty, S.},
```

I want to replace all instances of these in my file (agn.bib), using something like:

```
sed "s/{\'{\i}/{\'i}/g" agn.bib
```

But that doesn't do anything, and I can't find the answer on Stack Overflow how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to *escape the backslash twice*; once for the shell, once for the `sed`:

```
sed -i "s/{\\\\'{\\\\i}/{\\\\'i}/g" file
```

since backslash is a metacharacter for both.

When you say `sed "\\\\"`, due to double quotes, `sed` actually receives `\\`, and according to the rules of basic regular expressions, treats the backslash as a literal character.

Comment: Thank you. This works and seems like the cleanest solution.

Comment: Done. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i 's/{\\'\''{\\i}/{\\'\''i}/g' file
```

Replace a `\` by quoting it i.e. `\\` and match a`'` by passing it through to the shell i.e. `'\''`.